# get the element of a previous div

Tags: jquery, html

I have below code:

```
    <ul>
    <li id="1">same html structure as below...</li>
    .....
    <li id="42">
    <div class="input-prepend">
       <button class="btn btn-small companyListBtn addMarkerBtn btn-primary btn-warning" type="button">   </button>                                                                                   
       <input class="input-medium companyListInput" maxlength="60" type="text"/>
       <button class="companyListBtn editCompanyBtn" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="42Div" class="companyAddressDiv">
       <input type="text" id="test" class="companyAddress" placeholder="Enter the Address"/>
       <button  class="btn btn-small compAddressSubmit" style="height:30px;margin-top:-9px;" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Now in the below code i am trying  to change the information on the **addMarkerBtn** located within the same list....  :(because there are multiple lists with same structure)

```
 $(document).on('click','.compAddressSubmit', function () {
    var addMarkerBtn = $(this).prev("div.row").find('.addMarkerBtn');
    //wanna make changes to the addMarkerButton .. something like..
    addMarkerBtn.removeClass('btn-primary btn-warning').addClass('btn-success');
    }
```

Tried closest(), next() but couldnt get it work. Any help please...

Comment: If there are multiple divs containing `#compAddressSubmit`, your document is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique. Sounds like your buttons with the `id` `compAddressSubmit` should have that as a class instead.

Comment: where is your `<div class="row">` in your code??

Comment: Ah, I see you've changed it now, to use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks for the support guys.... sometimes simple things stop our progress.... its really great to learn and let others learn...cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
 var addMarkerBtn = $(this).parents("li").find('.addMarkerBtn');
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>If there are multiple divs containing `#compAddressSubmit`, your document is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique. Sounds like your buttons with the `id` `compAddressSubmit` should have that as a class instead.</s>

Assuming you make that change, then: *(I see you've made that change in your question.)*

So:

```
$(document).on('click','.compAddressSubmit', function () {
    var addMarkerBtn = $(this).closest("div.companyAddressDiv").prev().find('.addMarkerBtn');
    addMarkerBtn.removeClass('btn-primary btn-warning').addClass('btn-success');
}
```

`$(this).closest("div.companyAddressDiv")` finds the `companyAddressDiv` containing the button. `prev` goes to the previous element (the `div` above it), then `find(".addMarkerBtn")` finds the button within that `div`.

If there's any chance the structure might change such that the element just prior to the `div.companyAddressDiv` won't be the one you want, you can use `.prevAll("div.input-prepend").first()` to get that `div` instead of just `.prev()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var addMarkerBtn = $(this).parents().eq(2).find('.addMarkerBtn');
```